# "Switch Scenes" in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx, scene

This is not a question.

I didn't find anything about it on the internet, so I tried to do it myself and I had a pretty good idea that I want to share for the people who search it in the future.

When you google "Switch scenes Java" it says: "Switch scenes using JavaFX", but I don't want to work with JavaFX and stay with Java Swing.

Then I had that brilliant idea, which I want to show you in the following:
(Im not a professional programmer or anything, Im 16 years old and a pupil, so my code won't be perfect)

The idea is to use multiple JFrames and set the location relative to eachother. Then set the not running JFrame to visible(false) and dispose() it.

Here is the code I wrote:

1. Creating the class for the first JFrame and the ActionListener to switch between the two JFrames:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class mainTest {
 
    public static JFrame frame1;

    JLabel hello1;

    JButton b1;
    
    
    static Handler handler;
    
    
    mainTest(){
        frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.setSize(900,600);
        frame1.setResizable(false);
        frame1.setTitle("Frame 1");
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(GUI2.frame2);
        frame1.setLayout(null);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
            
    
        handler = new Handler();
        
        hello1 = new JLabel("Hello Frame 1");
        hello1.setBounds(100,100,100,20);
        frame1.add(hello1);
        
        
        b1 = new JButton("Go to Frame 2");
        b1.setBounds(100,300,200,50);
        b1.addActionListener(handler);
        frame1.add(b1);
        
        
    }
    
    public class Handler implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == b1) {
                
                new GUI2();
                
                frame1.setVisible(false);
                frame1.dispose();
                
            }if(e.getSource() == GUI2.b2) {
                
                
                new mainTest();
                
                
                GUI2.frame2.setVisible(false);
                GUI2.frame2.dispose();
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new mainTest();
    }
    
}
```

2. Create the class for the second JFrame:

```
mport javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class GUI2 {

    public static JFrame frame2;
    public static JButton b2;
    public JLabel hello2;
    
    GUI2(){
        
        frame2 = new JFrame();
        frame2.setSize(900,600);
        frame2.setResizable(false);
        frame2.setTitle("Frame 2");
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(mainTest.frame1);
        frame2.setLayout(null);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        
        b2 = new JButton("Got to Frame 1");
        b2.setBounds(100,300,200,50);
        b2.addActionListener(mainTest.handler);
        frame2.add(b2);
        
        hello2 = new JLabel("Hello Frame 2");
        hello2.setBounds(100,100,100,20);
        frame2.add(hello2);
    }
    
}
```

How it works:

1. class:

- Creating the constructor and initialize all objects.
  --> setLocationRelativeTo(frame2);
- Creating the ActionListener class inside the first class
- In the ActionListener Class check which button is pressed and call the other class depending on which button was pressed.
- Last set the frame to visible(false) and dispose() it, depending on which frame should be seen and which should not be seen.

2. class:

- Creating the constructor and initialize all objects.
  --> setLocationRelativeTo(frame1);

Thats all. If you there are ways to do it better, then please tell me. I just didn't find anything on the internet.

Bye :)

Comment: _This is not a question._ then it doesn't belong into the question section :) Instead, separate the text into a question and answer part, keep the question part as .. question and move the answer part into the .. answer section.

Comment: Please don't use `null` `LayoutManager`s because they exist exactly for configuring the location and size of each `Component`.

Comment: One way would be to use a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) with each scene on its own JPanel.  You can then show the scenes in whatever order you wish.  Since you're learning, the Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will take you through the steps of creating a Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of other ways to do this in Swing that I can think of (ie there may be others too):

1. Change the content pane of your (single) `JFrame`. As far as I know, this is a better practice than *switching entire frames/windows*.
2. Use a `Container`, inside your (single) `JFrame`, with [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and just *switch cards* when desired. As far as I know, this is a better practice than the previous case.

#### Example for case 1:

This is a bit straight forward: [change the content pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane-java.awt.Container-) of the `JFrame` whenever you like, then [revalidate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate--), [repaint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint--) and restore the location (and size) of the frame in the screen. Actually repainting, even revalidating may be optional here, I am not sure, but they are usually (if not everytime) needed when you change the `Component` hierarchy.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainContentPaneSwitching {
    
    private static class ChangeContentPaneListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel newFrameContents = new JPanel(); //Uses FlowLayout by default.
            newFrameContents.add(new JLabel("You have successfully changed the content pane of the frame!", JLabel.CENTER));
            
            /*We assume that the source is a JButton and that the Window is of type JFrame, hence
            the following utility method call is possible without letting any errors appear:*/
            JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((JButton) e.getSource());
            
            frame.setContentPane(newFrameContents); //Change the content pane of the frame.
            frame.revalidate(); //Notify the frame that the component hierarchy has changed.
            frame.pack(); //Resize the frame as necessary in order to fit as many contents as possible in the screen.
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Place the frame in the center of the screen. As you can tell, this needs its size to calculate the location, so we made sure in the previous line of code that it is set.
            frame.repaint(); //Repaint frame with all its contents.
        }
    }
    
    private static class MainRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JButton changeContentPaneButton = new JButton("Click to go to the next content pane!");
            changeContentPaneButton.addActionListener(new ChangeContentPaneListener());
            
            JPanel frameContents = new JPanel(); //Uses FlowLayout by default.
            frameContents.add(changeContentPaneButton);
            
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("My application");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Tells the frame that when the user closes it, it must terminate the application.
            frame.setContentPane(frameContents); //Add contents to the frame.
            frame.pack(); //Resize the frame as necessary in order to fit as many contents as possible in the screen.
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Place the frame in the center of the screen. As you can tell, this needs its size to calculate the location, so we made sure in the previous line of code that it is set.
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MainRunnable()); //Swing code must always be used in the Event Dispatch Thread.
    }
}
```

Notice that `revalidate` and `repaint` belong to the class `Component`, which also means that they are *inherited* as they say to the `JFrame` (because `JFrame` is a `Frame` which is a `Window` which is a `Container` which is a `Component`). By *inherited* I mean that they can be used by the `JFrame` class itself and its instances, as if the `JFrame` had declared them. You may already know this, I just mention it for the sake of introduction.

#### Example for case 2:

`LayoutManager`s handle the location and size of each `Component` added to a `Container`.

`CardLayout` is a `LayoutManager` which does the switching you are looking for. Each *card* is a `Component` with whatever contents it needs, and if you add those *card* `Component`s to a `Container` which has `CardLayout`, then you can tell the `CardLayout` to switch between those *cards*. *Switching cards* is like *switching scenes* as you describe it, although it does so without the need to change the `Container`! Be it a content pane, be it an entirely new `JFrame`, it just changes which child `Component`s are visble and which are not.

To use it, you can have a look at the following example code (and of-course read the API documentation and related tutorials):

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainCardLayoutSwitching {
    
    private static class ChangeContentPaneListener implements ActionListener {
        private JPanel cardsParent;
        
        public ChangeContentPaneListener(JPanel cardsParent) {
            this.cardsParent = cardsParent;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /*We assume that 'cardsParent' uses a CardLayout, hence the following method call is
            possible without letting any errors appear:*/
            CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) cardsParent.getLayout();
            
            layout.show(cardsParent, "SUCCESS_CARD"); //Actual content switching.
        }
    }
    
    private static class MainRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JPanel frameContents = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
            
            JButton changeContentPaneButton = new JButton("Click to go to the next card!");
            changeContentPaneButton.addActionListener(new ChangeContentPaneListener(frameContents));
            
            final JPanel changeContentPaneButtonParent = new JPanel(); //Uses FlowLayout by default.
            changeContentPaneButtonParent.add(changeContentPaneButton);
            
            JLabel successMessageLabel = new JLabel("You have successfully changed the card of the panel!", JLabel.CENTER);
            
            frameContents.add(changeContentPaneButtonParent, "BUTTON_CARD");
            frameContents.add(successMessageLabel, "SUCCESS_CARD");
            
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("My application");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Tells the frame that when the user closes it, it must terminate the application.
            frame.setContentPane(frameContents); //Add contents to the frame.
            frame.pack(); //Resize the frame as necessary in order to fit as many contents as possible in the screen.
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Place the frame in the center of the screen. As you can tell, this needs its size to calculate the location, so we made sure in the previous line of code that it is set.
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MainRunnable()); //Swing code must always be used in the Event Dispatch Thread.
    }
}
```