# Main function finishing before ActionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

For a school project, I have 2 different interfaces - a login and a "selection" interface.
When I click the Login button, I want the login interface to close and the selection interface to open.

The issue I'm getting is by the time the ActionPerformed function is called, my login interface becomes null, even though it is still shown on screen and I can still interact with it(?).

Why is the lface even becoming null? I'm new to JFrame, so any help would be appreciated!

This is my code

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class testmanager implements ActionListener {
    private SelectionsUserInterface sface;
    private SelectionData sdata = new SelectionData();
    private LoginUserInterface lface;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand() == "Login") {
            System.out.println("login button");
            InitializeSelectionInterface();
            DeleteWindow(getLface());
        }

    }

    private void InitializeSelectionInterface() {
        sface = new SelectionsUserInterface(sdata);
    }

    private void DeleteWindow(JFrame window) {
        System.out.println(window);
    }

    public LoginUserInterface getLface() {
        return lface;
    }

    public void setLface(LoginUserInterface lface) {
        this.lface = lface;
    }

}
```

and this is my main method

```
public class testmain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        testmanager m = new testmanager();
        m.setLface(new LoginUserInterface());


    }

}
```

Comment: I can’t really tell what you’re trying to accomplish, but if it’s switching between two panels, you should look into the CardLayout. Refer here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-awt-cardlayout-class/amp/

Comment: What's a `LoginUserInterface`? I'd guess the main interface is never set visible, but for more than guesses.. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You can check out another (possibly duplicate) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66906630/switch-scenes-in-java-swing). The question might not seem similar (or it might seem so), but the solutions are similar to what you are looking for. It just happened I posted an answer on it 2 days ago. It uses 2 methods: (1) change the `JFrame`'s content pane and (2) use a `CardLayout`. Just click the button in each case, to switch to the next panel.

Comment: Based on your title, yes, the main function finishes long before the user even sees the first JFrame.  Java Swing is event-driven.  Your follow-up code needs to be executed in your login button ActionListener.